# Java design pattern for limiting available methods for a returned object

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance

I'm a new Java/OO programmer. I would like to create a method (referred to below as `myMethod`) which returns one of ***n*** types of objects based on inspecting input parameters and the state of the world. Say here ***n == 2*** for simplicity: `myMethod()` can return an object of either type `Foo` or `Bar`.

Foo and Bar have different methods available to call on them, some exclusive and some in common, such as:

```
ReturnType? myMethod(inputs) {
    if (/*examining state of world & inputs implies a Foo*/)
        return new Foo();
    return new Bar();
}
...

public class Foo {
    public Foo() {}
    public void x() {...} //common to Bar
    public void f() {...}
}
public class Bar {
    public Bar() {}
    public void x() {...} //common to Foo
    public void b() {...}
}
```

What design pattern should I use for `myMethod()`, and for the classes Foo and Bar? If my method's return type is a superclass (or an aggregation?) of Foo and Bar or if Foo & Bar implement some common interface, then is there a way for clients who receive objects from `myMethod()` to be able to safely call `f()` or `b()` on the returned object without needing to use object introspection or casting?

Or is this design an anti-pattern, and is there an obvious rewrite I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: The exact scenario as you describe doesn't seem to make sense - your client code would need to know whether to call 'f' or 'b' anyway, so what's the advantage of having a single creation mechanism?  It sounds like your client code would be expecting two different objects with completely different behaviors in different code paths.  It sounds like what you want to do is [segregate interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) for each of the three behaviors (x, f, and b). Foo & Bar would both implement the interface for x and Foo would also implement 'f' and so forth

Comment: Indeed @val-akkapeddi I currently have separate interfaces 'f' and 'b' which are extensions to 'x', and Foo and Bar implement only the appropriate extension. This seems to require casting from the callee, however, and it appears to me a common interface, with 'f' and 'b' throwing exceptions unless overloaded, will result in cleaner code for the callee.

Comment: Deliberately raising exceptions never results in cleaner code - you'll be using exceptions as flow control, calling the wrong methods and then attempting to handle the fallout instead of avoiding getting in that situation in the first place - right?  Casting is also nasty and unecessary in this case imo.  The way I would do this is to have Foo:Ix,If and Bar:Ix,Ib. You must be making a decision in code to call f - have that code only refer to its object through the interface If, and hide access to the classes behind factory methods of type If, Ix, Ib IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No pattern - you can't do it with knowing the type and casting.

You either have to pull those methods up to the common interface or parent class OR cast.  There's no "pattern" to save you - that's magical thinking.

Comment: Is there a favored method in Java or is this often project-specific style? If I do the former, I could throw an exception if someone with a Foo tries to call `aFoo.b()` but once _n_ grows large, the common interface will just be throwing tons of exceptions. Casting seems to place more burden of knowledge on the callee however.

Comment: You can write a factory and return a reference of the interface or supertype, but you can't and shouldn't control what users choose to do with it once they have it.  It does place a burden of knowledge on the callee, but it places a greater one on the designer.  Callees should deal with the interface type they're given and not need to cast.  If they do, your design is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the design pattern you are looking for is the *Factory* design pattern which is pretty commonly used in the OO paradigm. You can read more about this pattern [here](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html). I am not completely sure what you are trying to achieve but I think this design pattern is at least worth looking at.

Comment: Factory is correct - it'll return a reference of the common interface or superclass type.  But it won't help with the problem of accessing the methods that are not in the interface or supertype without resorting to casting.

Answer (score 0):

Well in java you can make implicit upcasting to the interface but you must use explicit downcasting or your java won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you are trying to do is very close to an anti pattern.

Since the type of object returned depends on "the state of world", do you expect the calling method to inspect the exact type of returned object, and behave different depending on the type?

I think you need to sit back, and try to explain what the use case for this design is, and then maybe we can help you with a better solution.

Comment: A callee following the expected specification would know whether to expect a Foo, Bar, etc back from myMethod, but if a callee makes a mistake I think gracefully failing will entail throwing an exception. A calling method use case would here be, in GUI automation, if a user asks for a form (the `Foo`), the user can provide character input to (`f()`) but if a user asks for a button (a `Bar`) the user should not be able to provide input, only click. `myMethod` is the point of contact for providing automatable elements.

Comment: But why would that implementation require the same method to return either a form or a button? - It seems to me now that what you need is a way for all components in your system to implement an interface which describe exactly what kind of input they support, and a way to get a new interface with the extended functions. Which bring me back to: I don't know exactly what problem you are trying to solve, but I am pretty sure your approach is wrong, so try to sit back, and describe what you are trying to do, not how you think it should be implemented.

Comment: Your own description is what I'm trying to achieve in fact :) - I think Val's comment above is what I need to emulate - I will try to request and return specific Foo or Bar objects from the calling method , and remove `myMethod()` as a monolithic single point of contact.